# Q: How can I evade storing duplicated users with Sails?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have coded a very simple sails app that just has  passport authentication implemented. I use mongoDB as local database and I can't get to deny the creation of users with duplicated email. (I already have unique: true in the email attribute). Any idea what could I be missing?

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        email: {
            type: 'email',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 6,
            required: true
        },
       toJSON: function() {
           var obj = this.toObject();
           delete obj.password;
           return obj;
       }
    },
    beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    user.password = hash;
                    cb();
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Here I create users:

```
signup: function (req, res) {
  User.create(req.params.all()).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
    req.login(user, function (err){
      if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
      return res.redirect('/welcome');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: That's the right way to do it. If you show us your code, we may be able to spot a typo or misuse that causes the error.

Comment: Since you have made email as `unique: true`, the ORM should throw an error while making a duplicate entry. Can you post the code. That should help understand better.

Comment: I just updated with my User.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get errors when adding users is to check the `Error` object returned by the `User.create()` method (Promise or `exec()` method).

Example with Bluebird Promise :

```
User.create({ email : 'foo@bar.com', password : 'secret' })
.then((newUser) => {
  /* do something with newly created user `newUser` */
  /* eg : return res.view('user/added.ejs', newUser); */
})
.catch((err) => {
  /* do something with the Error object `err` */
  /* It should tell you if email already exists */
  /* eg : return res.badRequest(err.message); */
});
```

Example with `exec()` method :

```
User.create({ email : 'foo@bar.com', password : 'secret' })
.exec((err, newUser) => {
  if (err) {
    /* do something with the Error object `err` */
  } else {
    /* do something with newly created user `newUser` */
  }
});
```

Comment: I have updated the post with the function I use to create a user. I think it looks quite like the second method.